# Error JSON.parse using ajax con pusher PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json

I have a problem sending a couple of parameters by using the library pusher ajax php.

It fails me: `SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data`

**code PHP and JS:**

```
<script src="https://js.pusher.com/3.0/pusher.min.js"></script>

<?php $this->load->view('scripts_ini'); ?>

<!-- inline scripts related to this page -->
<script type="text/javascript">

    var pusher = new Pusher('9999999999999999');
    var channel1 = pusher.subscribe('puntaje_channel1');

    channel1.bind('msg_puntaje1', function(rpta) {
        console.log('+>'+rpta);
        $('#sp_puntaje1').html(rpta);       
    });


    $(document).ready(function() {

        $('.puntaje1').click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();

            var puntaje1 = parseInt($('#sp_puntaje1').text());          

            $.ajax({
                url: 'push_puntaje1.php',
                type: "POST",
                dataType: "json",
                data : {
                    message: val_res,
                    socket_id: pusher.connection.socket_id
                }
            }).done(function(rpta) {
                console.log('->'+rpta);
                $('#sp_puntaje1').html(rpta);
            }).fail(function( jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
                console.log('error, '+errorThrown);     
            });


        });

    }); 
</script>
```

**code PHP:**

```
<?php
require 'Pusher.php';

$mensaje1 = $_POST['message'];

$pusher1 = PusherInstance::get_pusher();

$pusher1->trigger(
    'puntaje_channel1',
    'msg_puntaje1',
    $mensaje1,
    $_POST['socket_id']
);

echo $mensaje1;
?>
```

Error firefox:

```
POST http://localhost:8005/sportipd/page/push_puntaje1.php


messaje=3&socket_id=154278.1632118

error, SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data
```

I hope you can help me with my problem.

Answer (score 0):

You're getting a json parse error because you **aren't** sending `json`, you're sending `text/html`.

Change this line `echo $mensaje1;` to this:

```
echo json_encode($mensaje1);
```

You would also do well to set the `Content-Type` header to json, to ensure it's read as such from within your PHP code:

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
```

Comment: Dear and I did and I still generates the same error.

Comment: @Hernando there must be an error then, can you check your Network tab on your browser, look for the ajax request and see if there are any PHP errors thrown.